# Vertx OAUTH2.0 Access Token Error: NoSuchKeyIdException

Tags: oauth-2.0, access-token, vert.x, quarkus, vertx-httpclient

I am using vertx to generate OAuth2 token with client credentials, Here is code snippet

```
<artifactId>vertx-auth-oauth2</artifactId>
<version>3.9.1</version>
```

OAuth2ClientOptions credentials = new OAuth2ClientOptions()
.setClientID(clientId)
.setClientSecret(clientSecret)
.setFlow(OAuth2FlowType.CLIENT)
.setTokenPath("oauth/token URL");

```
    OAuth2Auth oAuth2Auth = OAuth2Auth.create(Vertx.vertx(),credentials);
    JsonObject tokenConfig = new JsonObject();

    oAuth2Auth.authenticate(tokenConfig, res ->
            {
                if (res.failed()) {
                    log.info("Access Token Error;" + res.cause().getMessage());
                } else {
                    User token = res.result();
                    log.info("token:" + token);
                }
            }
    );
```

**ERROR:**
**Access Token Error;io/vertx/ext/jwt/NoSuchKeyIdException Stack Future{cause=io/vertx/ext/jwt/NoSuchKeyIdException}**

Answer (score 0):

The configuration above is manually specifying the endpoints to the `IdP` server, and after a valid authentication the response included a `JWT` token as response. What `vertx-auth-oauth2` is trying to do is parse this token, however no security keys have been loaded so it can't accept the token as valid.

It is expected to see this exception as a warning if there is not handler for the event, but it looks like you are getting the exception while parsing the token.

I suspect that this could be a bug, could you provide a simple example that reproduces the exception so I can further investigate?

Comment: Here is the code and you can add the dependency In order to replicate the issue.

https://docs.google.com/document/d/13N4-yXyraihogSMIBVpzAa_jomIurr5GkF8fE88KEbs/edit?usp=sharing